# How can I write intetgration tests Spring Web Client(Spring MVC) with Oauth2 when using Credentials Flow

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-oauth2, java-17

I have an **Oauth 2 client** that actually interacts with another microservice that acts as an authorization server (auth-server).
I have an endpoint (use spring mvc). It has the annotation

```java
@PreAuthorize("has Scope(T(.........).
```

```java
@Configuration
public class AuthWebClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedManager(
        ClientRegistrationRepository client,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClient
    ) {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedProvider =
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder
                .builder()
                .authorizationCode()
                .refreshToken()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedManager =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                client,
                authorizedClient
            );

        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedProvider);

        return authorizedManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauthClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedManager) {
        return new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedManager);
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthClientManager {

    public static final String SERVICE_ID = "my-service";
    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager oAuth2Manager;
    private final ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction
        filterFunction;
    private final WebClient webClient;
    private WebClient client;

    public WebClient getClient() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(client)
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest =
                    OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId(SERVICE_ID)
                    .principal(SERVICE_ID)
                    .build();
                client = webClient
                    .mutate()
                    .filter(
                        (request, next) -> next
                            .exchange(
                                ClientRequest.from(request)
                                    .attributes(
                                        oauth2AuthorizedClient(
                                            oAuth2Manager.authorize(authorizeRequest)
                                        )
                                    ).build()
                            )
                    )
                    .apply(filterFunction.oauth2Configuration())
                    .build();
                return client;
            });
    }
}
```

- endpoint

```java
@RequestMapping("email")
public interface RestController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasScope(T(......MESSAGE_SEND)")
   
    @PostMapping("v1/message")
    ResponseEntity<Void> send(@Valid @RequestBody Dto dto);
}
```

- implementation of endpoint

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class RestControllerImpl implements RestController {

   
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> send(Dto dto) {


       return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new ScopeAwareExpressionHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(
        HttpSecurity http,
        @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider-uri}") String hostname
    ) throws Exception {

        

        return http
            .cors()
            .configurationSource(request ->
                new CorsConfiguration()
                    .applyPermitDefaultValues()
            )
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .requestMatchers(
                requestMatcherConfigurer -> requestMatcherConfigurer.antMatchers("/**")
            )
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequestsCustomized -> authorizeRequestsCustomized
                .antMatchers(
                    "/swagger-ui/**"
                )
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer ->
                httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer
                    .jwt()
                    .jwkSetUri(hostname + "/oauth2/jwks")
            )
            .build();
    }
}
```

- application.yaml

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          my-service: # my-service
            provider: spring
            client-id: 1
            client-secret:1
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            scope: message.send
            client-name: 1
        provider:
          spring:
            issuer-uri:locachost....
            user-info-uri: locachost..../api/v1/users/me
            user-name-attribute: id
```

A would like to write an integration test for this endpoint to verify that the **Oauth2** client for **Credentials flow** is configured correctly. well, for one thing, the work of my endpoint.

How could I do that ?

I have not found any examples suitable for my task.

Could someone share knowledge about this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write integration test:

- start authorization server
- script query to get authorization token with WebClient or something
- set test request Authorization header with bearer token you got.

I'd rather write unit tests with @WebmvcTest or @WebfluxTest bfluxTest and configure test security context with jwt() MockMvc post processor (or Word bTestClient mutator) from spring-security-test or @WithMockJwtAuth from https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons

Comment: thank you for responding. But our situation is as follows: Credentials flow is used. My service, in order to perform the required task from another service, must to obtain from authserver -jwks.   then  that the service must check that client-service (backend) is authorized and its token is valid.

Comment: I have a security config. which specifies where to download jwks    from. .oauth2 Resource Server(httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer ->
http Security OAuth2 ResourceServer Configured
.jwt()
.jwkSetUri(issuerHostname + "/oauth2/jwks")
and this whole case needs to be covered with an integration test. I don't even know how to approach this task.

Comment: Then load your security config, read the jwks conf and apply what I answered: post a query to the authorization server to get an access-token and use it for your requests to other service.